# showing a xml file contents in a dbctrlgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, xmlmapper

I have a win application project that should be done in delphi2010.

In a form something like the image below,should be produced:

[image]
www.up.iranblog.com/Files2/1e867ce0de784c469496.jpg

First the image of product and under that tha name and the price.

The information should be read from a xml file, but I don't know how to display the information in dbctrlgrid?

Please help

thanx in advance

Answer (score 3):

For [DBCtrlGrid](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/e/index.php/DBCGrids.TDBCtrlGrid), it is just like a normal panel control. The difference is, it creates this panel for every record in your dataset. So you should put your data-aware or ordinary controls in the panel anyway you like, and your panel will be automatically repeated for each record in the  dataset, and if the controls on your panel are data-aware, then they will receive data of the connected fields for each corresponding record. You can check DBCtrlGrid entry in Delphi help for more information.

If you want to use DBCtrlGrid for presenting your XML data, then you should first present your XML data as database records. To do so, you should first create a XML transformation file using [XML Mapper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_XMLMapper) tool. After that, you can use a [XMLTransformProvider](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/e/index.php/Xmlxform.TXMLTransformProvider) control, and connect it to your transformation file, and your XML data. XMLTransformProvider would transform your XML data to database records using the provided transformation file.

Now you can connect a [ClientDataset](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/e/index.php/DBClient.TClientDataSet) to your XMLTransformProvider, and your XML data would be available in your ClientDataset as database records. You can connect a [DataSource](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/e/index.php/DB.TDataSource) to your ClientDataset, and connect your DBCtrlGrid to that datasource, so that your DBCtrlGrid control would present the data available in ClientDataset.

So the data flow is somehow like this:

XML Data -- (Transformed to database records) --> Data Provider --> ClientDataset --> DataSource --> Data-aware controls (e.g. DBCtrlGrid).

**P.S.** From your provided link, it seems you are located in Iran. The included links cannot be accessed from an IP located in Iran, so the web pages won't load. You can read the same documentation from Delphi's installed help files. Just drop each component on the form, and press F1.

Comment: @Ken White, information about why the provided link cannot be accessed inside Iran is not a rant! Embarcadero does not give any useful message to the visitors from Iran, telling them that they are not allowed to visit the online documentation. All they get is a browser error telling them the specified URL cannot be reached. So it is useful for them to know that it is not a problem with their own connection or Internet service provider, rather it is an Embarcadero policy.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea somebody moving around in a site like this, and editing posts that contain anything against policies of a particular company. This is not Embarcadero newsgroup!